# Can't wake with external keyboard/mouse when the lid is closed

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, suspend, mouse, power-management

I have a laptop running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS which is connected to an extenal monitor, while the  built-in display is off (and the lid is closed). I have an external wired keyboard and mouse and when I suspend the computer I would like to be able to tap a key or click the mouse and the computer would wake up again. However, this is not the case and I end up having to lift off all the things I have sitting on my laptop and pry open the top so the computer wakes up and the monitor detects it. How could I fix this?

Comment: Perhaps you shouldn't have "things" on top of the laptop? Just sayin'... Now, waking up from suspension is hardware dependent, not software or OS. So, either yours have some firmware setting that needs to be enabled in order to wake up from external USB devices or it simply can't. This has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: Check your BIOS for a setting that keeps the USB ports powered on at all times.

Comment: @ChanganAuto We have a new user here... so please be gentle.

Comment: @heynnema THANK YOU!!! It worked beautifully. It took so long to get this little gem of an answer! Kudos to you :)

Comment: when I get the ubuntu grub screen I can only use the laptops keyboard, not any usb one. see Answer 1 I suppose.

Comment: I have the same issue ; when I touch the USB keyboard, it lights up, but XPS 13 does not wake up.

Comment: @axd Does the XPS 13 internal keyboard wake it up? Wired or wireless external USB keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments...

Check your BIOS for a setting that keeps the USB ports powered on at all times.

Comment: Same issue: KUbuntu 20.04; the external USB keyboard lights up when I hit a key, but the OS does not wake up.
Worst of all, there was a time in some previous release where the keyboard would be able to wake up the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this on my Dell XPS 13 Plus 9320 running Ubuntu 22.04.1 by turning off the lid switch in BIOS.